# What is the distribution of the ratio of sums of squared normal random variables?

Tags: distributions, self-study

Given that $Y_1, \ldots, Y_6$ are independent normal random variables with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Find the distribution of the following
$ T=\displaystyle\frac{Y^2_{1}+Y^2_{2}+Y^2_{3}}{Y^2_{4}+Y^2_{5}+Y^2_{6}} $

Comment: Two `homework` questions consecutively, I think you need to tells us what have you tried.

Comment: the thing is that I do not know how to start so I posted it here. Any hints would be very much appreciated. Full solutions are not required. Cheers.

Comment: Hint: divide the numerator and denominator by $\sigma^2$. Note that if $Y\sim Normal(0,\sigma^2)$, then $Y/\sigma\sim Normal(0,1)$. Investigate the distribution of the square of a standard normal variable (hint':chi-squared) and then the distribution of the sum of these variables when they are independent. Finally, find the distribution of the ratio, there is a well-known relationship. You do not need to do all the calculations, just find the relationships. Keywords: standard normal, chi-squared distribution, F-distribution.

Comment: That's very much a detailed explanation. Thanks indeed.

Comment: I would add the term degrees of freedom because when you find the right form for this distribution you will also need to know how to determine the degrees of freedom to uniquely specify this distribution.

Answer (score 6):

To close this one:

We can write
$$T= \frac {\sigma^2}{\sigma^2} \cdot\frac{Y^2_{1}+Y^2_{2}+Y^2_{3}}{Y^2_{4}+Y^2_{5}+Y^2_{6}} = \frac{(Y_{1}/\sigma)^2+(Y_{2}/\sigma)^2+(Y_{3}/\sigma)^2}{(Y_{4}/\sigma)^2+(Y_{5}/\sigma)^2+(Y_{6}/\sigma)^2}$$

All these are now independent squared standard normals. The sum of such is a chi-square random variable with degrees of freedom equal to the number of the squared standard normals summed. So both the numerator and the denominator are chi-squares each with $3$ degrees of freedom.

So (abusing notation)
$$T= \frac {\mathcal \chi^2_3}{\mathcal \chi^2_3} = \frac {\mathcal \chi^2_3/3}{\mathcal \chi^2_3/3}$$

The ratio of independent, as is the case here, chi-squares, each divided by its degrees of freedom, is an [$F$-random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution) that inherits the degrees of freedom, as its own parameters. So

$$T \sim F(d_1=3,d_2=3)$$

Note that for "denominator" ($d_2$) degrees of freedom equal or lower than $4$, as is the case here, the variance of the distribution is not defined, and one has to use other measures of dispersion.